# How can I set a non-continuous date filter?

Tags: tableau-api

I need to be able to filter my data to comparable weeks/months across various years. And I need to be able to update those choices on the fly. Is there a way in tableau to set a non-continuous date filter?

because the base data is saved on the tableau server, I'm unable to join additional tables to it, so my initial idea of making a table of year / start date / end date and joining that to my data with a simple t/f filter isn't panning out.

I've considered making series of parameters, but it seems like it might get a bit overwhelming to make so many

Other things I've considered is writing an extended rule like

```
IF [year] = 2015 THEN [date]BETWEEN(date A, date B)
```

or the **tableau equivalent** to `BETWEEN`

```
ELSEIF [year] = 2016 THEN [date]BETWEEN(date C, Date D)

ELSE IF //and so forth
```

Does anyone else have experience with this?  Any strategies you might recommend on the parameters vs. a long formula?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Standard tableau filters on dates allow filtering by both continuous date ranges or filtering by parts of dates.

For example, if you wanted to compare January sales cross multiple years, you can drag your date field to the filters shelf and then right-click the date field in the shelf and choose "Discrete" rather than "Continuous" or choose "Month" in the upper set of options about which date component you want (the upper set selects date components, the lower set selects date ranges with in filters and axes).

So, if you put a date field on the filters shelf and select "month" as a discrete you will get a filter that allows you to filter for every January in the dataset.

Comment: thanks, let's say I need to be more granular than a calendar month?  like 9/19/16 through 2/25/16 compared to 9/25/17-12/31/17 compared to 9/24/18 through 12/30/18, but then next week I want to extend each date range out a week

Comment: @LEFE There are many other options for interpreting dates discretely in Tableau. eg. Days of month, days of week, hours and so on. What you want might require a combination of those but if you are going for very irregular combinations of dates you are going to have to use them in a calculated field (with some logical mixture of discrete dateparts).

Comment: Thanks. I know that I need something beyond the basic tableau date functions, which is why I'm asking for advice from anyone else who's encountered this issues.  I am considering options re: calculated fields vs user input parameters, but both have drawbacks.  I just want to know how others might have addressed this

Comment: @LEFE if you are comparing weeks then you can redefine the week to start off the day you want and use the week number to compare different weeks (and this doesn't need calculated fields: it can be done directly with filters).

Comment: thanks, Matt, I really appreciate how much thought you've put into this.  using week numbers would be the ideal solution, except the traditional calendar weeks do not line up with our business model.  We are more similar to an academic year, where the number of weeks for each "year" are not always 52, and the starting dates for each "year" are also not aligned with a traditional calendar year.  I have a table of the "years" and "weeks" but they are not joined to my data, and cannot be by me, as the data is on the server, and cannot be joined to